# Define a function to multiply a string by number using python

Tags: string, jupyter

[image]

the code is not working on local Python

[image]

but it runs fine in online jupyter notebook.

why is this happening? thanks a lot

Comment: you need to be more clear and fix this 
enter image description here

Answer (score 2):

In the first image, the cmd.exe doesn't do automatic indentation. After the first line you should include four spaces. Now, in the command line you have:

```
def whatever(a):
return a*2
```

It should be:

```
def whatever(a):
    return a*2
```